# Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any) while returning Promise in action-creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

In my Redux actions creator, I am returning a Promise which has to resolve/reject depending upon the success/failure of async api call.

I'm using next.js with typescript.
Code is working fine but typescript implementation is showing error - `Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any)`

Codesandbox demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-clarke-1p1m4?file=/pages/index.tsx

```
/* component file */

const Index = (props: any) => {
  const [isFetching, setFetched] = useState(false);
  const getDataFromStore = useSelector((state: any) => state.todos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.fetchData())
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(`fetched data`, response);
        setFetched(false);
      })
      .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
    console.log("data-", getDataFromStore);
  }, [isFetching]);

// rest of the codes follow here.


/*  actions.tsx */

// fetch data from server
export const fetchData = () => (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
  console.log(`action created, fetching data`);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .get(API_PATH)
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        resolve(response);
        dispatch(FETCH_DATA(response.data));
        dispatch(API_SUCCESS("DONE"));
      })
      .catch(async (err: any) => {
        reject("error");
      });
  });
};
```

Please go to pags/index.tsx and see line no 13. on pages/index.tsx You will notice a type error - `Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any)`

[image]

How to resolve this types bug?

Comment: How did you define COURSE_API.ADD_COURSE

Comment: All information necessary to understand the question, must not be behind a link.

Comment: hey @trincot I've updated the question. Hope it is helpful for you now to help me resolve my issues :)

Comment: To resolve the type issue for dispatch, I had to use another library called @reduxjs/toolkit and then export a dispatch to use in my components file. How to resolve this types bug without this workaround. I don't have the need of redux-toolkit library otherwise. I feel there should be store dispatch exported with correct types to ensure working of promise returning actions creator.
Workaround - https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper/issues/311